# Методы расширения

Tags: c#

Ребят я изучаю C# и дошел до темы Методы расширения.Можете объяснить что это,как работаю,и как правильно их применять?

Comment: [Видосик](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YvRm-0jrN8c) в тему.

Comment: Метод расширения - это по сути статический метод, который можно вызвать удобным способом, как будто он часть класса.

Answer (score 1):

> Методы расширения (extension methods) позволяют добавлять новые методы в уже существующие типы без создания нового производного класса. Эта функциональность бывает особенно полезна, когда нам хочется добавить в некоторый тип новый метод, но сам тип (класс или структуру) мы изменить не можем, поскольку у нас нет доступа к исходному коду. Либо если мы не можем использовать стандартный механизм наследования, например, если классы определенны с модификатором sealed.  (https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.18.php)

1) Методы расширения (extension methods) могут быть только статическими и могут объявляться только в статических классах. 
2) Методы расширения могут быть использованы как обычные методы (дальше)
 Пример мой, еще вариант есть на Метаните (ссылка в цитате)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //  1st way
        int a = 1;
        int b = 1;
        Console.WriteLine(a.Add(b));            //  2



        //  2nd way
        a = 1;
        b = 1;
        Console.WriteLine(MyClass.Add(a, b));   //  2
    }
}

static class MyClass
{
    public static int Add(this int a, int b)    //  Раширяемым будет именно первый аргумент метода, помеченный ключевым словом this
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.Уже немного разобрался.Огромное спасибо)))